# Chess Problem Database with PGN or FEN

Tags: problems, database, pgn, fen

Is there a database of chess problems that have the game or positions PGN and or FEN?

Comment: Most databases consist of full games. What type of puzzles are you looking for?

Comment: Checkmate puzzles primarily

Comment: Depending on what kind of chess database program that you are using, you can always search for setups that you are looking for.

Comment: I have a hardcopy book "The Chess Problem" by HJC Andrews containing deep 2/3/4 movers. I'm planning to collect every puzzle, not from games but those constructed problems

Answer (score 15):

Some large chess puzzle databases with links:

- Free open source collection of 1,743,871 Problems at [chessblunders.org](https://chessblunders.org/), collected from more than 6 million games from professional tournaments.. They have an API for access to database.
- Taken from the website ["wtharvey"](http://wtharvey.com/):

  - [Mate in 2](http://wtharvey.com/m8n2.txt)
  - [Mate in 3](http://wtharvey.com/m8n3.txt)
  - [Mate in 4](http://wtharvey.com/m8n4.txt)
- From the website "[the art of mate in 2](https://sites.google.com/site/edusadier/theartofdirectmateintwomoves)"

  - Nearly ~[152000 puzzles](https://sites.google.com/site/edusadier/home/Mate%20en%20Dos.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) in pgn format
  - You will also find four pgn files of ~ 500 puzzles made by "Argentine problemists"
- Browsable collection of problems at "[Yet another chess problems database](http://www.yacpdb.org/#search/ODg4ODg4ODgvLy8vLy8vLy8vLy8vMS8xLzEvMA==/1)". There are ~420000 problems. Not sure whether it can be downloaded programmatically. In the "[About](http://www.yacpdb.org/#about)" page, you will find more links, some of which are broken.

Answer (score 6):

http://gorgonian.weebly.com/pgn.html

https://exeterchessclub.org.uk/downloads (in chessbase format)

Exeter chess club has many other valuable resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can also buy Harold Van der Heidjen's endgame study database. It contains more or less all the endgame studies he could gather from the old classic (Saavedra, Ponziani etc..) to the most recent from every publications  and composing tournaments out there. And everything in between (Troitsky, Rinck, Platov brothers, Kubbel, Kasparyan, etc..).

Back when I bought it in 2004 it contained 58000 chess endgame studies, but the most recent versions have most likely over 100k.

Answer (score 2):

https://lichess.org/training it is a very good place for puzzles there are more than 2000000 in lichess you can download them from https://database.lichess.org/#puzzles and there are a lot of themes
ex:-

- [Master Games](https://lichess.org/training/master)
- [Mate in 1](https://lichess.org/training/mateIn1)
- [Super GM games](https://lichess.org/training/superGM)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind playing on mobile, chesspuzzleblitz.com has a playable database and it lets you compete.

Also, chessbluders.org and www.yacpdb.org are great resources too.

Answer (score 0):

The [lichess puzzles are free to download](https://database.lichess.org/#puzzles) and use, with FEN and annotation of themes, openings, ratings, ...
However, they do not come as a pgn file, but as a csv file, so you need to process the file first if you intend to open it using a regular PGN viewing software.